# How to sum up unique cell values based on a condition?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

In D10 I want to sum ColumnD values (in rows 2:9, derived with a VLOOOKP formula) but each only one time for each distinct ColA value:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
Test2   testlast2   ttttt   1         *
Test2   testlast2   ttttt   1
Test4   testlast4   ttttt   1         *
Test5   testlast5   ttttt   1         *
Test6   testlast6   ttttt   -BLANK-
Test7   testlast7   ttttt   -BLANK-
Test7   testlast7   ttttt   1         *
Test7   testlast7   ttttt   1
```

In the example above the result should be `4` as indicated by asterisks.

I have tried formulae like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9&""))
```

(which returns `5`) without success.

Comment: I don't know if this simply a typo or not but one of your `A2:A9` ranges is `A24:A9`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this *array* formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((D2:D9<>"")/COUNTIFS(D2:D9,"<>",A2:A9,A2:A9&""),0))`

*Array* formulas require <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than simply `Enter`.

---

Here is another *standard* formula version that will never allow a `#DIV/0!` to occur so no need for `IFERROR`:

`=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D9<>"")/(COUNTIFS(D2:D9,"<>",A2:A9,A2:A9&"")+(D2:D9="")))`

Comment: @ Tim,the array formula indeed worked for achieving the result of 6. but i wanted to have my output as 4.
Condition 1: when col A & B matches then i DONOT want to add up instead i will consider once (i.e, for test2 here has 2 rows and summed up value as 2 but having considered this for same Test2 i wanted to have the output as 1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D2:D9,E2:E9)
```

with, in E2 copied down to E9:

```
=1*(COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2)=1)
```

Comment: awesome, it exactly served my calculation. thanks a lot!!!